# Why am I receiving run-time error 2147024809 (80070057) in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error, report, ms-access-2007

When I attempt to save a report as a .pdf (through a form) I receive a run-time error and I have no idea what to do to the code to fix it.  It does save the report even though I get the error, but it saves it as a File file type instead of .pdf.  This is the current code:

```
Private Sub cmdPDF_Click()

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptPDFAllClasses", acFormatPDF, "rptPDFAllClasses", True

Me.Visible = False

End Sub
```

When I select debug the Me.Visible = False is highlighted. I am very new to VBA so I apologize for my (surely) obvious ignorance.

Comment: Your output path should be the fullpath for the file being created - including ".pdf" file extension. You should also add error trapping in case the report is empty (no records) or file already exists - and you get a proper error message returned.

Comment: Thank you, @dbmitch!  I modified the file path and added the code to trap the error.  It runs perfectly now.  I sitll don't know what could be causing the error, but as long as my report saves properly and I don't have my DB users receiving an error (especially when they have that little Debug option and they are curious) it's not really an issue.